# Brakeman generates Command Injection warning when using Nokogiri to open an user inputed url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, brakeman

I encountered a problem with my rails project.
Brakeman gem generates Command Injection warning when using Nokogiri to open an user inputed url. This is my code

```
    require 'open-uri'
    url = params[:url]
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("#{url}", "User-Agent" => "Ruby/#{request.user_agent}"))
```

And this is brakeman's warning message

> Possible command injection in open() near line 101: open("#{params[:url]}", "User-Agent" => ("Ruby/#{request.user_agent}"))

Does anyone know the solution that can fix brakeman's warning? Thank you!

Comment: Don't use the `"#{x}"` anti-pattern. Just use `x`.

Comment: @tadman i have tried but the same result :(

Comment: That's just a bad habit you need to shake. The answer is posted below.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting this warning because `open` can open a lot of things, URLs being just one of them. If someone sends in a "url" of `|rm -rf /` then you're in for a bad time because the leading `|` character indicates "open using shell and get output".

This warning is serious. Pay attention to it and **DO NOT** send in arbitrary parameters to `open`. If you're looking to fetch just URLs, use an HTTP library like [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) to do that reliably and safely. `open-uri` is a quick and dirty hack that can get you into trouble.